# ModX Revo package installer hangs on console

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I am trying to install packages on a fresh instance of ModX. I can download (and upload) packages fine but when I hit install the Console appears but does nothing - it just says

> "Console running..."

and no commands appear.

If I close the Console window it will say the package is installed but it will not work.

Would anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Any errors in apache logs?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this can be due to mod_security settings in your hosting providers PHP settings. Worth contacting them to see if they can adjust the settings to avoid your ModX package installs being flagged up and blocked.